# Docker run error: “Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found”

Tags: docker, .net-core, processor

I am using docker to build and run two services, one a .net core website and the other a .net core processor. I have the website up and running just fine. When I try to run my processor however, I get the following error message:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found. Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-chores.processor.dll does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

- My website, which is working, has an identical Dockerfile except for the dll name.
- I have run the dotnet build and publish commands manually and they run successfully.
- I have verified that the `dotnet publish` command generates a dll named "chores.processor.dll" (same capitalization)

My processer dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.100 AS build
COPY /src /all/src

WORKDIR /all/src
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
# COPY --from=build /app .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "chores.processor.dll"]
```

Processor csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>Chores.Processor</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
        <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.59.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Website csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
        <PackageReference Include="MySqlConnector" Version="0.59.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It seems odd to me that the error message appears to be looking for `dotnet-chores.processor.dll`; why is it prefixed with “dotnet-”?

If anyone has any suggestions on what I can do to further debug this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: When it looks for `dotnet-` it's typically because the assembly wasn't found, and the `dotnet` CLI tries to look for a tool with that naming convention.  Keep in mind stuff in linux is typically case sensitive, try updating your `ENTRYPOINT` to have the proper casing of the assembly, I assume `Chores.Processor.dll`.

Comment: Try replacing the entry-point wih a `ENTRYPOINT ["find", "-iname", "chores.processor.dll"]` to find out if the file name is differently cased.

Comment: @Matthew @Omair-Majid I ran `docker run -it image` with an Dockerfile with entrypoint of `ENTRYPOINT ['/bin/bash']` so I could see exactly what was being copied/generated in the container, and verified that `chores-processor.dll` (exact capitalization) was there. Still no luck.

Comment: In your previous comment, you referred to it as `chores-processor.dll` (note the hyphen) but in your Dockerfile you use `chores.processor.dll` (note the period).  Is that the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *chores.processor.dll* can't be found because the correct name is *Chores.Processor.dll* - Linux is case sensitive. So:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Chores.Processor.dll"]
```

or

```
CMD dotnet ./Chores.Processor.dll
```

The error message is misleading in the sense that it adds a dash.